# excel vba code error(subscript out of range)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi all I had a code in excel vba that makes me able to change sheet name according to cell value i right click on sheet name then select (view code ) then paste the code it worked well with the sheet i did a simple macro that copy the sheet content into another new sheet then paste the code that changes the sheet name with the cell value but i got an error i just need a macro that add new sheet and copy the current sheet content into the new and make the sheet name dependent on cell value (b3)
i have 0 experience in visual basic
here is some screenshots
thanks for helping me
[image][image]
this the sheet name code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("B3")
    End If
End Sub
```

i have already explained that THAT

Comment: You are getting tha error because Excel is nto able to find a worksheet with the name `Sheet1`

Comment: How can i overcome this problem if u can modify code it will be better

Comment: i just need a code that enables me to copy current sheet , add new sheet, paste its content into a new sheet and make the new sheet name dependent on cell value (b3)

Comment: I can give you the code but that will not help with your learrning. I recommend you give it a try first and then if you get stuck, post the code that you tried and we will take it from there (*I promise*).

Comment: thanks man but I work as an electrical engineer so I am just an excel user so I tried to make a sheet that would help me in my work and I faced that problem so I asked for help

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Copy of the Active Sheet

- Copy this code into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyActiveSheet()
    
    ' In the worst case scenario, you'll end up with an additional worksheet
    ' that could not be renamed. If you want to keep this worksheet,
    ' set DeleteIfCannotRename to False.
    Const DeleteIfCannotRename As Boolean = True
    
    ' Invalidate the active sheet.
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf sh Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Create a copy.
    sws.Copy After:=sws
    
    ' Reference the copy.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Write the value form 'B3' to a variable.
    Dim dName As String: dName = CStr(dws.Range("B3").Value)
    
    Dim ErrNumber As Long
    
    ' Prevent error if a sheet with the same name already exists
    ' or the value in 'B3' doesn't contain a valid worksheet name.
    On Error Resume Next ' turn on error-trapping
        ' Attempt to rename.
        dws.Name = dName
        ErrNumber = Err.Number ' store the error number in a variable
    On Error GoTo 0 ' turn off error trapping
    
    ' Delete and inform. Out-comment or delete the 'MsgBox' line(s)
    ' if the message box is too annoying.
    If DeleteIfCannotRename Then ' will delete
        If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                dws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            MsgBox "Could not rename to '" & dName & "' so it got deleted.", _
                vbCritical, "CopyActivesheet"
        End If
    Else ' will not delete
        MsgBox "Could not rename to '" & dName & "'.", _
            vbCritical, "CopyActivesheet"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much . it worked perfectly but when I try to change b3 value the sheet name don't change can u help me with that in case I changed b3 the sheet name change with it.b3 has a drop list .thanks for ur patience

Comment: Is the code you have posted already in the worksheet?

Comment: no I deleted it

Comment: can i send the file to u ? the main problem i cant change sheet name once it changed  the first time it renamed and i have to put the next sheet name in the current b3 before the code work , i need to change sheet name according to b3 value when i start new sheet he copy it but the new sheet is named with its default one untill i  change b3 value again